# AdMob lagging game

Tags: ios, swift, admob, lag

Whenever the connection on my phone isn't perfect (so ads don't load instantly) my game lags to death.

Here's my code which I can confirm I call once/scene in my game:

```
func showAd(){
    banner = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)

    var frame = banner.frame
    frame.origin.x = (self.view?.bounds.width)! / 2 - frame.size.width / 2
    frame.origin.y = 0// - 350
    banner.frame = frame

    banner.adUnitID = "xxx000xxx"

    banner.rootViewController = gameViewController

    let request: GADRequest = GADRequest()

    banner.load(request)

    banner.delegate = self as? GADBannerViewDelegate

    self.view?.addSubview(banner)
}

func hideAd(){
    banner.removeFromSuperview()
}
```

Thanks for your help I really need this fixed.

I also get this notif in the console every time an ad loads successfully:

> Could not signal service com.apple.WebKit.WebContent: 113: Could not find specified service

Comment: I would suggest you use the Time Profiler instrument to see where your app is spending time.  Also, you shouldn't add the subview until you have received an ad, as indicated by a call to the `adViewDidReceiveAd` delegate method

Comment: Just tried it with that but there's still huge amounts of lag if a person goes back an forth between scenes before the ad loaded in that scene. Is there any way I can cancel loading an ad when they leave the scene if it never loaded in time? Right now I just use .removeFromSuperview

Comment: As I said, I wouldn't even add the banner view until the ad has loaded.  Where do you call `showAd()`?  There is a chance you are adding multiple banner views.